# How can a client located in a container communicate with a server that is not located in a container?

Tags: c, docker, network-programming, serversocket

The host has a server that listens on local host port 6969 and a client that accesses this port. Communication occurs via a socket.

How can communication between the client and server be implemented if the client is stuffed into a docker container? How to correctly configure port forwarding?

I created a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc:latest
COPY ./src/client.c /home
WORKDIR /home
RUN gcc client.c && ./a.out
```

I collected the image and launched it with the command:

`docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9697:9697 -it clientcont`

Comment: I believe you are looking for this, if I understood your description of the scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach